# What is the difference between locking and atom/reset!/swap! in Clojure

Tags: clojure, synchronization, locking, atomic

I was reading some source code and came across `locking` usage in Clojure. It made me thinking about the atom version. So what are the differences between 2 code snippets, I think that they do the same thing?

```clj
(def lock (Object.))

(locking lock
  ...some operation)
```

```clj
(def state (atom true))

(when @state
  (reset! state false)
  ...some operation
  (reset! state true))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locking (aka synchronization) is only ever needed when multiple threads are changing a piece of mutable state.

The `locking` macro is a low-level feature that one almost never needs to use in Clojure.  It is similar in some ways to a synchronized block in Java.

In clojure, one normally just uses an `atom` for this purpose. On rare occasions an `agent` or `ref` is called for.  In even rarer situations, you can use a dynamic Var to get thread-local mutable state.

Internally, a Clojure `atom` delegates all currency operations to the class `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference`.

---

Your code snippet shows a misunderstanding of an atom's purpose and operation.  Two concurrent threads could process your atom code snipped at the same time, so the attempt does not provide thread safety and would result in bugs and corrupted data.

---

If you want to explore the *really* primitive (i.e. Java 1.2) synchronization primitives, see:

- The [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)
- The book [Effective Java](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java-3rd/9780134686097/) (1st edition shows most details, 3rd Ed. defers to higher-level classes)
- The book [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-concurrency-in/0321349601/)  This book is so scary it'll turn your hair white. After reading this one, you'll be so afraid of roll-your-own concurrency that you'll never even think about doing it again.
- [Double-Checked Locking is Broken](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html): A excellent example of how hard it is to get locking right (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java)).

Comment: Yup. Use Atoms, refs and agents. That will cover most use-cases